# How can I download occurence data with multiple values, using rgbif?

Tags: r

The rgbif function to download data [allows](https://docs.ropensci.org/rgbif/articles/downloading_a_long_species_list.html) for multiple values to be included in a predicate, such as data that's about 7 families of bees, and not just 1 family for example. I keep getting this error:

```
Error: 'value' must be length 1
6.
stop("'value' must be length 1", call. = FALSE)
5.
pred_factory("=")(key, value)
4.
pred("year", 1923:2023)
3.
parse_predicates(user, email, type, format, ...)
2.
occ_download_prep(..., body = body, type = type, format = format,
user = user, pwd = pwd, email = email, curlopts = curlopts)
1.
occ_download(pred_in("familyKey", beeFamilyKey), pred("country",
"US"), pred("year", 1923:2023), format = "SIMPLE_CSV")
```

To use a vector, it requires for the predicate function to be **pred_in**, which is what I'm using. It should look something like this.

```
beeFamilyName <- c('Apidae', 'Halictidae', 'Megachilidae', 'Andrenidae', 'Colletidae', 'Melittidae', 'Stenotritidae')
beeFamilyBackbone <- name_backbone_checklist(beeFamilyName)
beeFamilyKey <- beeFamilyBackbone$usageKey
gbifDL <- occ_download(pred_in("familyKey", beeFamilyKey),
                       pred("country", "US"),
                       pred("year", 1923:2023),
                       format = "SIMPLE_CSV")
```

I'd expect it to immediately begin downloading data of those 7 families, in the U.S. from 1923 to 2023.